# Change current date color in MaterialCalandarView

Tags: android, colors, android-widget, android-calendar, calendarview

I am using [`MaterialCalendarView`](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview). Here is the code:

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_space"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@dimen/very_small_text_size"
    app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"/>
```

I want to give black boundary to current date, How can I give that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the color of all selected dates, you have to add this line to your xml:

```
 app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/yourColor"
```

and to select the current Date:

```
calendarView.setDateSelected(Calendar.getInstance(),true);
```

If you want to set a different color only for the current date you have to add a Decorator to your MaterialCalendarView:

```
 calendarView.addDecorator(new DayViewDecorator() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
            Calendar cal1 = day.getCalendar();
            Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

            return (cal1.get(Calendar.ERA) == cal2.get(Calendar.ERA)
                    && cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                    && cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        }

        @Override
        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.selector));
        }
    });
```

Where selector is your custom selector.xml, for example:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@color/yourColor"
    />

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/yourColor"
    />

<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Selector Reference Link: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/CUSTOM_SELECTORS.md

Decorator Reference Link: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md